# PHP sessions over ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have built a php backend library, for a ios app of mine, and I am using sessions to know if the user is logged in. But for some reason, even after setting the session variable, when I try to retrieve it, it is retrieved as undefined, making my app think the user isn't logged in, even though the user is logged in. Is there any alternative for using sessions, or did I setup my session wrong? Here is the code:

Login call:

```
session_start();
// Login stuff
$_SESSION["id"] = /* My id, which isn't undefined */;
```

Checking whether user is logged in or not:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
    $id = isset($_SESSION["id"]);
    echo $id;
    // do stuff
}
else {
    echo "You are not logged in.";
    // user not logged in
    // This condition is always called, and I am not able to change it no matter what I do.
}
```

Comment: Is your app sending the session cookie correctly?

Comment: My app doesn't send any information related to the session, it only sends the user login information

Comment: how u are calling the script the url should be relative..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not relying on cookies or tokens, and using the database. The user is logged out after half an hour. I modified my users table in mysql, and added 2 new columns, `loggedIn` as a `boolean`, and `lastLoggedIn` as a `timestamp`. From there, I checked if it has been half an hour after logging in, if yes, change the loggedIn to false, or else, the user is logged in.

Comment: sounds like you basically just re-implemented the PHP session functionality using a database. To be fair, this might actually be a reasonable solution if you have clustered webservers - ASP.NET offers a similar thing out-of-the -box, using a DB to store the session state. You just have to watch performance if you have a lot of users, as DB calls are comparatively expensive tasks in terms of CPU, network I/O etc.

Comment: Does it cope with the same user being logged in on multiple devices? Each should really be treated as a separate session. Can sessions persist beyond 30 mins? Mobile apps often persist logins for days and weeks at a time, usually by using refreshable tokens. This takes some UI pain away because typing credentials on a mobile device is tedious and slow.

Comment: @ADyson, Good point, I didn't think about that. Now that I test it, you are right, that is a problem. Perhaps I can generate a unique code for every device which has a account, and each account can only be used on one device.

Comment: Why limit an account to one device? Would be pretty annoying if say, your bank did that! What you want is a unique code for every _session_. Sessions may be on different devices. They may even be on the same device (e.g. two separate browser windows!). Basically, you end up with either server-side sessions again, or tokens. No need to re-invent the wheel here.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This answer refers to the code originally posted, which has since been edited by the OP.

`if ($id = $_SESSION["id"]) {`

should be

`if ($id == $_SESSION["id"]) {`

i.e. `==` not `=`.

A single equals will *set the value of* the left-hand variable, and the result, assuming that `$_SESSION["id"]` is actually set will *always* evaluate to `true` . If `$_SESSION["id"]` is null or not set, then the expression will always evaluate to `false`.

A double equals *compares* the two variables.

However, a more conventional solution would simply be:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
```

Comment: I meant to use a single = on purpose, I am assigning the variable id to that value in the if statement

Comment: If you're assigning the variable, then you're not comparing the variable, and therefore you can't use an if statement in that context.

Comment: @KingCoder11 `if ($id = $_SESSION["id"]) {` will always resolve to  TRUE

Comment: Ok, I will change my code to `if (isset($_SESSION["id"] ))`

Comment: I just ran the app with the updated code, @RiggsFolly, you are right, the reason I though it wasn't is because I have multiple session variables which have the same else statement, with a different if.

Comment: I will change the code to the right code in my question

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry I had used a standard variable, not session. Realised my mistake a couple of minutes ago, and deleted now. Apologies for wasting time!

Comment: @ADyson :) not a problem

Answer (score 1):

Ajax request wont save the session cookie by it's own, You may wanna use JWT tokens

Take a look at this [JWT tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/)

Comment: who mentioned ajax? The client is an iOS app. But yeah tokens are a good security solution.

Comment: The title, my bad. But I need something that will work for ajax as well.

Comment: @KingCoder11 Sessions and tokens will both work equally well over ajax or a conventional HTTP request.

Comment: i don't know about iOS but i think it's like Android, they both use ajax request, JWT access tokens is the best way to go. just like Facebook, Google, etc

Comment: @ADyson, In that case, maybe I should use my database to do it, I can set the time of logging in, and check based on that.

Comment: @SouhailBenSlimene no, ajax is specifically a browser technology, with the restrictions inherent in that. Everything else just uses conventional HTTP requests, unless the app is deliberately built using a Web View or similar component.

Comment: you can do that but if you have a lot of users this will make your server overloaded, just try using access token

Comment: @ADyson i know that, but basically it's all the same, i think

Comment: for tokens yes it should work the same way, but not for other things such as CORS where an ajax context places restrictions on the client.

Comment: @ADyson to use CORS you just need to add a header in the response coming from the server

Comment: yes, I know. I've done it many times. But it's a key difference between ajax and other forms of request. That was the original point I was making, that ajax is _not_ the same - you said "basically it's all the same", but it isn't entirely the same, for this and a handful of other reasons. Similar, but not the same. And in programming, that can be significant. That's all I meant. Just to clarify for anyone reading the thread.

Comment: i agree on that

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
// On the first page
session_start(); // Login stuff
$user_id = 2; //or something from the database or via authentication.
 $_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;   /* My id, which isn't undefined */;
```

On the target page;

```
   session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){ 
    $id = $_SESSION["id"];
    echo " session id is set do your processing here.";
    }else{
      echo "session id is not set";
    }
```

Comment: This is going to the else statement.

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: The else statement is executing, in your example, the snippet is executing "session id is not set"

Comment: Then the $_SESSION['id'] is not set....you have to make sure it is set on the previous page by doing this. $_SESSION['id'] = $user_I'd;

Comment: I just update the code...follow strictly and your problem will b solve...make sure the user id is assigned to the Global session as $_SESSION["id"] the it will be available on all other part of the pages provided session_start(); is called...I hope this help. Thanks